# Dataframe change the value by looking at previous row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe, I would like to change the the 'lab' value to character B if the lab value of the previous row has a character 'E', except for the last row where 'lab' is an E

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  if i == len(df) - 1:
    pass
  elif df['lab'].iloc[i] == 'E':
    df['lab'].iloc[i] = 'B'
```

I wrote the following code, but it takes a long time to run and got the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:671:
SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer:

```py
df['lab2'] = df['lab'].shift()
df['lab'] = df.apply(lambda x:'B' if x['lab2'] == 'E' else x['lab'],axis=1)
df = df.drop('lab2',axis=1)
df.loc[df.shape[0]-1,'lab'] = 'E'
```

Why is it better? Let's run a time comparison.

Setup : Generate a random bigger dataframe.

```py
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
letter = ['B','E']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[letter[randint(0,1)] for i in range(50000)]]).T,columns= ['lab'])
```

Then carry out the operation using the two methods.

Time taken for my code to run:

```
1.36 s
```

Using loops, time taken:

```
16 s
```

A screenshot of the run in jupyter notebook: 
[image: Screenshot of time comparison]

Comment: thanks looping get Wall time: 1min 55s, with lambda get Wall time: 8.15 s for my 35k row dataset

Comment: Also, it's not about `lambda`. It's about not using loops and instead using the `apply` function. If you have difficulty in understanding any part of the code, I can update my answer with required comments.